# Wordpress Blog Is Very Slow

Tags: wordpress, page-speed

A few days, my website (http://www.teknoblogo.com) isn't scrolling easily (You can try scrolling) . Website very very slow. I'm using W3 Total Cache. Disabled all unnecessary plugins. But still website is very slow.

What can i do ?

Comment: How fast you can scroll down a page has nothing to do with the server-side performance. If your browser is acting sluggish, then the problem is likely your computer.

Comment: Maybe scrolling slowly because of some JS files? My other user's have same problem

Comment: It could be. Try disabling JS on your browser and then browse the page. But server-side caching, disabling WP plugins, etc. won't affect client-side performance.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try using something like Google Chrome's Developer Tools to see what elements of the page are taking longest to load.

[image]

This will give you an indication of what is slowing down the page load (i.e. you might be relying on too many external content sources which take a few seconds to respond)

Comment: What do you think ? Which files loading slow and shoould i remove it ?